# setting value's of a superclass (inheritence)

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I'm having some trouble setting the variables of a SuperClass

I have following classes:

  Computer(SuperClass)

  Laptop(SubClass)

  Desktop(SubClass)

In the SupperClass `Computer` I have a variable `string name;`

```
public class Computer
    {
        protected string name;
    }
```

When I call the method `ChangeName(string yourName)` from the laptop class, it should set the variable `name` in the SuperClass `Computer`, like this:

```
public class Laptop : Computer
{
    public void ChangeName(string yourName)
    {
        name = yourName;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the name ,with properties, from the Superclass `Computer`, it returns `Null`.
I debugged to see what happend, and the SubClass `Laptop` actually changed the name in SuperClass, but when the method `ChangeName` ended compiling, it was back restored to `null`.

What may have caused this?

Comment: Show the complete code of your classes.

Comment: This is the complete code, except for the imported libraries, but I don't think that makes a change?

Comment: Are you expecting the value of the `computer` _object_ to change by modifying the `laptop` _object_? That's not how inheritance works.

Comment: Yes Rik, that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are setting up the variable like

`laptop.ChangeName(name);`

and trying to get the name like

`computer.name`.

You are misunderstanding the **inheritance**.

Obviously that will be `null`. Because `computer` and `laptop` are two different objects. Laptop is inherited but it doesn't mean that you can access `computer` object using `laptop` object.

After setting up the values using `laptop.ChangeName(name);`. Print `laptop.name` and you will get the `name` you've set.